# Vue3-project: TypeScript checks don't seem to be exported in npm-package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, build, package

I'm trying to export a simple Vue3-component into a npm-package. I'm using vite and TypeScript. In that the component has a required property defined as so:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  example: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <p>{{ example }}</p>
</template>
```

If I now include this component in my `App.vue`, I expect an error if the `example` is not provided. That works.

But now I'm exporting it to an npm-Package and including it from there. On including the editor (VSCode) seems to forget to tell me, that there is a required property. Even if the console in the webbrowser logs a fitting warning.

My `tsconfig.json` is modified as shown here:

```
{
  //...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.cy.ts", "src/main.ts"]
}
```

The `vite.config.js` is as follows:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import { resolve } from 'node:path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), dts()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
    }
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'ExamplePackage',
      fileName: 'example-package',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

The `src/index.ts` only imports and exports the component:

```
import DemoComponent from '@/components/DemoComponent.vue'

export { DemoComponent }
```

My `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "@test/example-package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/example-package.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/example-package.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/example-package.js",
      "require": "./dist/example-package.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --ignore-path .gitignore --max-warnings=0",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  // ...
}
```

I'm building the project via `npm run build && npm pack`. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: The way it's implemented is always specific to a tool (VSC here)

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any hints in what to look out for? Documentation or anything (or only old/conflicting/not helpful information)? I‘m not able to find anything. For reference: I‘m using the volar-plugin.

Comment: These are the quirks that are never documented. This is the case for Volar's support, I suppose